# Problem with installing Grunt on Magento2

Tags: magento2, error, grunt

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.integer-net.com/magento-2-frontend-workflow-step-by-step/) on installing **Grunt** on Magento 2. I am running Magento 2.0.7, hosted with one-click app from digitalocean. I only have 'root' user (heard that may cause some problems).

After installing Grunt, the `grunt:clean`, `grunt:exec` commands work, but it gives error when trying to `grunt:less`. Error is:

Loading `Gruntfile.js` tasks...ERROR

> Error: Cannot find module './jit-grunt'
>   Warning: Task "less:raultheme" not found. Use --force to continue.

And after using `grunt:exec` I cant enter my page anymore, not even backend. It throws this error:

```
exception 'Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException' with message 'Can't create directory /var/www/html/magento/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/Response/Http/.' in /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator.php:103 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator/Autoloader.php(35): Magento\Framework\Code\Generator->generateClass('Magento\Framewo...') #1 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\Code\Generator\Autoloader->load('Magento\Framewo...') #2 [internal function]: spl_autoload_call('Magento\Framewo...') #3 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php(19): ReflectionClass->__construct('Magento\Framewo...') #4 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php(44): Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor('Magento\Framewo...') #5 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(71): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime->getParameters('Magento\Framewo...') #6 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(71): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\Framewo...') #7 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(236): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\Framewo...') #8 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(53): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\Framewo...', NULL, 'response', 'Magento\Framewo...') #9 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(82): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\Framewo...', Array, Array) #10 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(57): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\Framewo...', Array) #11 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(233): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\Framewo...', Array) #12 /var/www/html/magento/index.php(38): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framewo...') #13 {main}
```

Magento is on developer mode. I have no clue anymore what might be wrong...

Comment: You can follow this : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/219265/livereload-configuration-via-grunt/219573#219573

Answer (score 2):

Neither documentation nor the tutorial you're following mentions that you need to rename `package.json.sample` and `Gruntfile.js.sample` to `package.json` and `Gruntfile.js` respectively. Rename these two files and run `npm install` and `npm update`.

Make sure you have grunt installed globally as stated in the documentation/tutorial. Don't forget to remove your previously installed `package.json` and `node_modules`.

Please read the documentation: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css_debug.html

`grunt exec:theme` NOT `grunt:exec`